# MongoDB Java Aggregation - addToSet Multiple Fields

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to run a MongoDB aggregation to retrieve distinct nested Documents in a single collection using the Java driver.

How can I add more than one field into the Java Accumulators.addToSet document output?

For instance in MongoDB Shell this works:

```
db.systems.aggregate([{$unwind:"$planets"},{$group:{_id:"$surfaceType", distinct:{$addToSet:{radius:"$planets.radius", surfaceType:"$planets.surfaceType"}}}}])
```

Output: 
`planets:[{ "radius" : 10.0,"surfaceType" : "water"},{"radius":"100.0","surfaceType" : "rock"}, ...]`

But in Java this does not work:

```
collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.group("$surfaceType",Accumulators.addToSet("planets", {radius:"$planets.radius", surface:"$planets.surfaceType", ...}))));
```

Just dont quite understand the syntax required for the String Expression in addToSet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a document in the **[`addToSet`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/client/model/Accumulators.java#L136)** operator:

```
collection.aggregate(
    Arrays.asList(
       Aggregates.unwind("$planets", new UnwindOptions().preserveNullAndEmptyArrays(true)),
       Aggregates.group("$surfaceType",
            Accumulators.addToSet("planets", 
                new Document("radius", "$planets.radius")
                    .append("surfaceType", "$planets.surfaceType")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks chridam - always something easy